# Deploy application with database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am developping a C# 4.0 desktop application that uses a SQL Server Express 2005 database,  currently it is located in the mssql data folder. My client's machine doesn't have SQL Server installed (it will need a license) and i can't use SQL Compact database because the data will pass the 3Go limit in the compact version, so my questions are  :

- Is it possible to install my app in the client machine without SQL Server being installed?
- Can i include my database while deploying the app?
- Can SQL Server be installed on my client's machine, if it has been checked in the prerequisites when deploying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to install my app in the client machine without SQL
>   Server being installed?

It's depends, if the client is in the same LAN as your SQL DB server, then yes, otherwise, it is impossible to interact with remote SQL DB server if you're both not at the same network.

> Can i include my database while deploying the app?

Yes you can, look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database)

> Can SQL Server be installed on my client's machine, if it has been
>   checked in the prerequisites when deploying ?

There are light server versions for client environments, see [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Comment: I'm not sure what LAN has to do with anything - especially the installation.  1. Installation and execution are two different matters.  2. There are all kinds of ways to access a database server besides it being on the same LAN.

Comment: @Yair Nevet: Thanks a lot for your quick answer ^^, however, by yes i can include my database in the deployment process, does it mean i can install the app on the client machine without being in the same LAN ?

Comment: @user3715595 It means that the user will need to have a local DB and not a remote one, you will not have access to the data.

Comment: @Yair Nevet Alright :), i will create a backup and install SQL express

Comment: @Dan-o Well, the OP have a DB along with his application, he should support it somehow in the client-installation.